How to ensure that rounding is uniform using tbl_svysummary
I am trying to produce a descriptive statistics table from a survey object using the
gtsummary package. I want to include the differences in descriptive statistics depending on whether respondents voted for Trump or not. I don't know how to control the number of digits produced by add_differences(), so that it matches the rest of the table.
Here is some sample code:
# Load necessary packages
library(survey)
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

# Create a sample data frame with a weight variable
set.seed(123)
# Create a sample data frame
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  age_rs = runif(100, 18, 80),  # rescaled age variable
  income_by_20_rs = runif(100, 0, 1),  # rescaled income variable
  physical_health_poor = runif(100, 0, 1),  # continuous physical health variable
  all_religion1 = runif(100, 0, 1),  # continuous religious status variable
  racial_consciousness = runif(100, 0, 1),  # rescaled racial consciousness
  number_discrim_areas_rs = runif(100, 0, 5),  # number of discrimination areas (rescaled)
  vote_trump = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
  weights = runif(100, 0.5, 2)  # weight variable ranging between 0.5 and 2
)

# Create survey design object with weights
df_design <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = df, weights = ~weights)

# Make table using gtsummary 
tbl1 <- tbl_svysummary(
  data = df_design, 
  by = "vote_trump", 
  statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"), 
  include = c(age_rs, income_by_20_rs, physical_health_poor, all_religion1),
  label = list(age_rs = "Age", 
               income_by_20_rs = "Income", 
               physical_health_poor = "Poor Physical Health", 
               all_religion1 = "Religious Devotion"),
  digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(3,3)),
  missing = "no",
  type = list(c(age_rs, income_by_20_rs, physical_health_poor, all_religion1) ~ "continuous") 
  ) %>% 
  add_difference() 

tbl1

Unfortunately, I don't know how to round the difference and p-value column so that they match the descriptive statistics. I would also like to get rid of the CI column.
Below is an image of the table:


You can use the add_difference(estimate_fun) and add_difference(pvalue_fun) arguments to change the functions that round/format the estimates and p-values. Lastly, you can use modify_column_hide() to hide columns from being printed.
library(gtsummary)

# Create a sample data frame with a weight variable
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  age_rs = runif(100, 18, 80),  # rescaled age variable
  income_by_20_rs = runif(100, 0, 1),  # rescaled income variable
  physical_health_poor = runif(100, 0, 1),  # continuous physical health variable
  all_religion1 = runif(100, 0, 1),  # continuous religious status variable
  racial_consciousness = runif(100, 0, 1),  # rescaled racial consciousness
  number_discrim_areas_rs = runif(100, 0, 5),  # number of discrimination areas (rescaled)
  vote_trump = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
  weights = runif(100, 0.5, 2)  # weight variable ranging between 0.5 and 2
)

# Create survey design object with weights
df_design <- survey::svydesign(ids = ~1, data = df, weights = ~weights)

# Make table using gtsummary 
tbl1 <- tbl_svysummary(
  data = df_design, 
  by = "vote_trump", 
  statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"), 
  include = c(age_rs, income_by_20_rs, physical_health_poor, all_religion1),
  digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(3,3)),
  missing = "no",
) |> 
  add_difference(
    # round estimates to 3 decimal places
    estimate_fun = everything() ~ label_style_number(digits = 3),
    # round pvalues to 3 decimal places
    pvalue_fun = label_style_pvalue(digits = 3)
  ) |> 
  # hide the CI: you can run `show_header_names(tbl)` to see the underlying column names
  modify_column_hide(columns = c(conf.low, conf.high))

as_kable(tbl1) # convert to kable to display on stackoverflow




Characteristic
No N = 56
Yes N = 67
Difference
p-value




age_rs
48.274 (17.960)
50.115 (17.450)
1.842
0.625


income_by_20_rs
0.563 (0.299)
0.481 (0.242)
-0.082
0.171


physical_health_poor
0.437 (0.276)
0.519 (0.302)
0.082
0.179


all_religion1
0.449 (0.279)
0.536 (0.297)
0.088
0.151



Created on 2024-12-30 with reprex v2.1.1
